# Is the set of all function with this condition... countable?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A=\{f|f:\Bbb{N} \to \{0,1\},lim _ {n\to\infty} f(n) =0\}$, now is A countable ?

I think it is countable because if we let $K_n=\{f|f:\Bbb{N} \to \{0,1\}, for \ every \ n \le m f(m) =0\}$ then every $K_n $ is not empty,countable and $A=\bigcup _{n\in \Bbb{N} } K_n$ ,now A is countable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f:\mathbb{N}\to \{0,1\}$ has the property $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(n)=0$, then this means that $f$ is eventually $0$.

More precisely, there exists $N$ such that $f(n)=0$ for all $n\ge N$.

This means that $A$ is countable, because it is in bijection with the set of finite $\{0,1\}$ sequences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and you were practically there. 
For any $f\in A$ there exists $M=M_f\in{\mathbb N}$ such that $f(n)=0$ for all $n>M$.
Let, for each $M\in\mathbb N$ let $A_M=\{f\in A|M_f=M\}$.
It is easy to see that $A_M$ is finite for each $M$.
Finally $A=\bigcup_{M=1}^\infty A_M$ is the countable union of finite sets and hence is countable.